# accidental post of an answer to the wrong question

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted accidentally an answer written for [How can I redefine my macro to accept a charcode instead of a character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164442/4686) to the other question (which was linked to in the former one) [How to highlight all words of the form ^[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]* immediately following an equal sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/how-to-highlight-all-words-of-the-form-0-9a-za-z0-9-immediately-following), I then deleted it and posted it at the right place. Is there a way for the duplicate actually remaining on `tex.stackexchange` as deleted answer to be completely erased by moderators?

Comment: you can flag it for mod attention, even when deleted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't imagine the `flag` button was still functional! could you make this an answer so that I can upvote/accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can flag it for mod attention, even when deleted.

Answer (score 15):

Taken from [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244)

---

### What does deletion mean for a post?

Deleted posts are usually **not** physically deleted (that is, removed from the system); they're just hidden (AKA soft-deleted). This means they won't appear in search results or data dumps, and normal users following links to them will see [a 404 (not found) page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/404).

Moderators, and normal users with >=10k reputation, see all deleted posts. Moderators are able to undelete any deleted post. "10kers" may vote to undelete deleted *questions* (it takes three votes to undelete), but cannot undelete deleted *answers*.